# Embedding performing unexpectedly worse than multi-hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, keras, embeddings

I'm pretty new to ML and have set up a Keras model with a number of categorical features of users & items to predict positive reactions.

Each feature is a list of IDs from a database - i.e. `[1, 5, 18]` - related to either a user or item.

Initially I built a model that turns these lists into multi-hot encodings (using the `IntegerLookup` layer) before concatenating them all. This seems to work fairly well.

I've since learned about embedding and have converted the model to use a Keras `Embedding` layer. My hope would be that it should improve performance as it'll learn which options are similar to each other, but I find the following:

- If I use `GlobalMaxPooling1D` to flatten the embeddings I end up with a huge reduction in parameter numbers (from 1.4 million to 80k) but performance of the model is significantly worse. I tried using `GlobalAveragePooling1D` but this doesn't work. (I get a loss of NaN, I think because some of the features in my validation set are empty lists?)
- If I use a `Flatten` layer then the model performs slightly better with embeddings but the number of parameters is very large - 4 million - and I have to make sure all the feature lists are the same length.

Is this to be expected, or am I not using embeddings correctly? I'd hoped to get better predictions with fewer parameters but it is seemingly not possible.

The topography of my network is as follows

```
feature 1 (shape (128,))                 feature 2 (shape (128,))
        |                                         |
embedding 1 (mask_zeros=True)           embedding 2 (mask_zeros=True)
        \                                        /
         \______________concatenate_____________/
                            |
              GlobalMaxPooling1D or Flatten
                            |
              Dense(256, activation=relu)
                            |
              Dense(1, activation=sigmoid)
```